# Adjusting the affinity of an process for high core counts

Tags: powershell, cpu-cores

I want to adjust the affinity of my program, but the number of cores is high

Is there a way that I can set all cores on the app by PowerShell code?

The number of cores is 64, and sometimes we use 112 cores.

This is my code

```
PowerShell "$Process = Get-Process -Id 6048; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=All"
```

I searched all over google but couldn't find any code that uses all cores.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I cannot personally verify that the following works.

The [`.ProcessorAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity) is a *bit mask* implemented as a [`System.IntPtr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IntPtr) value.

However, the bit masks must only contain bits for cores that are actually available, so using `[IntPtr]::MaxValue` is *not* an option.

Assuming `112` available cores, you need to provide a bit mask with all possible bits *within the range of available cores* set to `1`, which you can calculate as follows:

```bash
$allCores = 
 [Math]::Pow(
   2,
   [Math]::Ceiling([Math]::Log2(112))
 ) - 1

(Get-Process -Id 6048).ProcessorAffinity = $allCores
```

Translated into a [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call from outside PowerShell:

```bash
powershell.exe "(Get-Process -Id 6048).ProcessorAffinity = [Math]::Pow(2, [Math]::Ceiling([Math]::Log2(112))) - 1"
```

---

Note: If you want to determine the number of available (logical) cores *programmatically*, use:

```bash
$totalLogicalCores = (
  (Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors |
    Measure-Object -Sum
).Sum
```